# Best method to create a c++ app to communicate with nginx

Tags: c++, http, node.js, nginx, fastcgi

I need to write a C++ interface that can read our data structure and provide the o/p based on query using http protocol.

**Server Need**
It should be able to serve 100 clients at the same time.

**Why C++**
All code is already written in C++. So we need to just write a http layer in C++. That's why I am choosing C++ instead of a more conventional web-programming language.

I am thinking to use nginx to serve static files and use its proxy pass to communicate with C++.

There are two approaches I have found:

- Write a FastCGI c++ module.
- Write a node.js c++ module.
- Please just any other suggestion if you have

Can you please list the pros and cons for each method based on prior experience?

Comment: You might want to change the question wording.  Which one is "best" is probably going to involve a lot of opinions.

Comment: You say "100 clients at the same time".  Do you really need the 100 connections to overlap, or are you looking for some specific througput (e.g. 100 "transactions" per second)?  If you have lengthy connections (in contrast to the usually short HTTP cycles), this might influence the answer a lot.

Comment: ok, I am thinking about the question title. Will change it if found can you please suggest one ?

Comment: I would recommend changing the last sentence more than the title.  You can change it for something like "can you list the pros and cons for each method based on prior experience" or something like that.  Just make sure it looks like a demand for facts, not opinions.

Comment: I will having 100 clients connected simultaneously. firing 2-3 query each second. 
and each query will take 20-200 ms for response. (not including http server response time )

Comment: Are the clients using persistent (keep alive) HTTP connections, or are the requests completely independent (most common scenario)?

Comment: @ André Caron 
It depends on the client. 
Nginx will be taking care about that. 
As my server will be running behind proxy. Connection will be getting close as soon as it served the nginx.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I will go forward with Nginx module devlopment http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html

Why ?

1. It don't require any other library dependency like fastcgi and
   other.
2. I can use all feature of nginx inside my module.

Comment: How did you make out with this?

Comment: @Homer6 The only reason I chosen nginx module for development was, i don't require any third lib.

Comment: Sounds good. Just wondering if you had success with that. If so, I may follow your path and write the module myself too. What was your overall impression of their module API?

Comment: This is more straightforward. http://nutrun.com/weblog/2009/08/15/hello-world-nginx-module.html

Answer (score 20):

No one here seems to have addressed the actual question, though some nice work arounds have been offered. I've been able to build C++ modules for nginx with a couple of minor changes.

1. Change the module source file name to end with `.cpp` so gcc realizes it is dealing with C++.
2. Make sure all your Nginx includes (e.g. `ngx_config.h`, `ngx_core.h`, etc.) are wrapped with an `extern "C" { }` structure. Similarly make sure any functions called through Nginx function pointers are declared with a wrapper.
3. Add `--with-ld-opt="-lstdc++"` to your "configure" invocation when setting up Nginx.

With those three steps your module should compile, build, link, and actually work.

Comment: Christopher, do you have a simple skeleton for that? Just curiosity

Comment: You have addressed the issue but without any code examples :)

Answer (score 11):

What you are asking is basically how to turn the c++ process that holds your data strutures into a webserver. That might not be the best way to go about it. (Then again, maybe it is in your situation. It depends on the complexity of the c++ process's interfaces you are trying to expose i guess.)

Anyways, I would try to stick a small http frontend in between the c++ process and the clients that could do the http work and communicate with the c++ backend process using some simple messaging protocol like [ZeroMQ/zmq](http://www.zeromq.org/).

[zmq](http://www.zeromq.org/) in c/c++ is fairly straight forward, and its very efficient and very fast. Using zmq you could very quickly setup a simple webserver frontend in python, or whatever language you prefer that has [zmq bindings](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3a_start), and have that frontend communicate asyncronously or syncronously with the backend c++ process using zmq.

The [c++ examples](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/C++) and [the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall) are nice starting points if you are looking into using zmq.

For Node.js there are also [a few examples](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/Node.js).

Comment: why write a webserver in python and connect to it with a socket, when you can just add sockets to your main application and serve http yourself?

Answer (score 4):

Try G-WAN, it allows you to use your c++ application directly.

Comment: You shouldn't answer old questions if your answer doesn't add anything to already accepted answers.

Comment: IMO, Always helpful to see more alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [nginx c function](https://github.com/Taymindis/nginx-c-function)

It is simple to use and built in nginx cache memory on apps layer, [wiki for nginx c function](https://github.com/Taymindis/nginx-c-function/wiki)

[Example project with cpp](https://github.com/Taymindis/sample-ngx-cfunc-project)

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ngx_http_c_func_module.h>

/*** build the program as .so library and copy to the preferred place for nginx to link this library ***/
/*** gcc -shared -o libcfuntest.so -fPIC cfuntest.c ***/
/*** cp libcfuntest.so /etc/nginx/ ***/

int is_service_on = 0;

void ngx_http_c_func_init(ngx_http_c_func_ctx_t* ctx) {
    ngx_http_c_func_log(info, ctx, "%s", "Starting The Application");


    is_service_on=1;
}



void my_app_simple_get_greeting(ngx_http_c_func_ctx_t *ctx) {
    ngx_http_c_func_log_info(ctx, "Calling back and log from my_app_simple_get");

    ngx_http_c_func_write_resp(
        ctx,
        200,
        "200 OK",
        "text/plain",
        "greeting from ngx_http_c_func testing"
    );
}

void my_app_simple_get_args(ngx_http_c_func_ctx_t *ctx) {
    ngx_http_c_func_log_info(ctx, "Calling back and log from my_app_simple_get_args");

    ngx_http_c_func_write_resp(
        ctx,
        200,
        "200 OK",
        "text/plain",
        ctx->req_args
    );
}

void my_app_simple_get_token_args(ngx_http_c_func_ctx_t *ctx) {
    ngx_http_c_func_log_info(ctx, "Calling back and log from my_app_simple_get_token_args");

    char * tokenArgs = ngx_http_c_func_get_query_param(ctx, "token");
    if (! tokenArgs) {
        ngx_http_c_func_write_resp(
            ctx,
            401,
            "401 unauthorized",
            "text/plain",
            "Token Not Found"
        );
    } else {
        ngx_http_c_func_write_resp(
            ctx,
            401,
            "401 unauthorized",
            "text/plain",
            tokenArgs
        );
    }
}

void my_app_simple_post(ngx_http_c_func_ctx_t *ctx) {
    ngx_http_c_func_log_info(ctx, "Calling back and log from my_app_simple_post");

    ngx_http_c_func_write_resp(
        ctx,
        202,
        "202 Accepted and Processing",
        "text/plain",
        ctx->req_body
    );
}



void my_app_simple_get_no_resp(ngx_http_c_func_ctx_t *ctx) {
    ngx_http_c_func_log_info(ctx, "Calling back and log from my_app_simple_get_no_resp");


}

void ngx_http_c_func_exit(ngx_http_c_func_ctx_t* ctx) {
    ngx_http_c_func_log(info, ctx, "%s\n", "Shutting down The Application");

    is_service_on = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an HTTP frontend to your C++ code, possibly using a library such as Beast, and then proxy_pass from nginx to your C++ server.  You may or may not need nginx at all, depending on your use.